# knockout tablesorter caching rows

Tags: knockout.js, tablesorter

I have been breaking my head with this issue for about 5-6 hours now.

I am using tablesorter in combination with knockoutjs. My problem is when using tablesorter,
the rows are cached and when I try to remove rows, they never disappear. I have created a jsfiddle explaining the problem. You can see my instructions in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/a8jUj/29/

I have been seeing a lot of articles which talk about this kind of issues but they all say that
we need to call a trigger update after a change to the table which I did but that didnt work for me.

```
 $("#list1").trigger("update");
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.tablesorter` plugin does not sort `self.users` array in your model, it sorts actual `<tr>` elements only. Your column sorter must call `observableArray.sort` method explicitly with customized comparer as argument:

```
self.sortCol = function(colName, event) {

    // get sorting direction
    var th = event.target;
    th.sortDir = (th.sortDir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');

    // array item comparator
    function comp(a, b){
        // get values to compare
        var av = a[colName](), bv = b[colName]();
        // compare using current direction
        if (th.sortDir == 'asc') {
            return av == bv ? 0 : av > bv ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return av == bv ? 0 : av < bv ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    // do sort
    self.users.sort(comp);
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8jUj/31/

P.S. Just for example I've bound `.sortCol()` via function to gain access to event object. You can rewrite your model to store current sorting parameters in model properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is that the table itself isn't empty, or contains only one row, when you update. Clearing the tbody, then add your row ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/a8jUj/33/)):

```
self.resetUsers = function (data, event) {
    self.users.removeAll();

    $("#list1").find('tbody').empty();

    self.users.push(new User({
        name: "Sidney",
        age: 26,
        active: 1
    }));

    $("#list1").trigger("update");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mottie. Even though this solution worked in the case of the jsfiddle I made, it didnt quite work for my actual app. I had to make sure the tablesorter plugin was called before I could load data into the observablearray bound to the ui for this to get my stuff working. Ofcourse I had to do something like what martinez had mentioned earlier as well.

Comment: @user1009036 If you are using the accepted answer, you really don't need tablesorter. It's all good :)